# How to get total column from awk

Tags: awk

I am testing `awk` and got this thought .So we know that

```
raja@badfox:~/Desktop/trails$ cat num.txt
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
4   1   2   31
raja@badfox:~/Desktop/trails$ awk '{ if ($1 == '4') print $0}' num.txt
4   1   2   31
raja@badfox:~/Desktop/trails$
```

so the command going to check for 4 at 1st column in filename num.txt .

So now i want output as there is a 4 at column 4 also and for example if i have 100 column of information and i want get the output as how many columns i have with the term i am searching .

I mean from the above example i want column 4 and column 1 as the output and i am searching for 4 .

Comment: I'm confused by the mention of the value 4 in column 3...can you clarify the question (because I cannot see any 4 in column 3)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry  now edited and looks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `NF` variable. It's the number of fields in the line.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
{
    if (NF == 8) {
        print $3, $8;
    } else if (NF == 9) {
        print $3, $9;
    } 
}
```

Or inside a loop:

```
# This will print the line if any field has the value 4
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ($i == 4)
        print $0
}
```

Comment: new to awk , could you place how i have to use it ?

Comment: The loop version will print the line once for each column containing 4, which is overkill, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You're absolutely correct. I just wanted to show a example of usage of the `NF` variable. If you feel the example could be made better, by all means do edit it and improve it :)

Comment: Worked and 2nd example suits for me . Thank you .

Comment: @August: Are you sure you understood the remark Jonathan made in the comment above? If separate fields have the value 4, the line `print $0` will be executed multiple times. Beware of that trap!

Comment: yeah yeah i am through that .

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find the rows which contain your search item (in this case, the value 4), and you want a count of how many such values appear in the row (as well as the row's data), then you need something like:

```
awk '{ count=0
       for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i == 4) count++
       if (count) print $i ": " $0
     }'
```

That doesn't quite fit onto one SO line.

If you merely want to identify which columns contain the search value, then you can use:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i == 4) column[i] = 1 }
     END { for (i in column) print i }'
```

This sets the (associative) array element `column[i]` to 1 for each column that contains the search value, 4.  The loop at the end prints the column numbers that contain 4 in an indeterminate (not sorted) order.  GNU `awk` includes sort functions (`asort`, `asorti`); POSIX `awk` does not. If sorted order is crucial, then consider:

```
awk 'BEGIN { max = 0 }
           { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i == 4) { column[i] = 1; if (i > max) max = i } }
     END   { for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) if (column[i] == 1) print i }'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all explanation .